# How to auth the issue permission to another contract?

Tags: smart-contract, permissions

I created a token "ABC" from account "tokenabc" and
deployed a airdrop contract "airdroptoken".

And I hope that everyone who transfers EOS token to this contract will get some airdrop token "ABC".

So here is my code:

```
asset sendAmout = asset(quantity.amount * 10, ABC_SYMBOL);
action(permission_level{get_self(), "active"_n},
               "tokenabc"_n,
               "issue"_n,
               make_tuple(to, sendAmout, std::string("suprise")))
       .send();
```

But it brings an error that tells me: wrong permission.

So how to handle this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
SEND_INLINE_ACTION(*this, issue, {{get_self(), "active"_n}},
                       {to, sendAmout, std::string("suprise"})
```